# timer not work when AlertDialog is showing

Tags: android

i have activity that show AlertDialog when special event rises but i want a timer running 
when this AlertDialog is showing to do something but timer not work.
AlertDialog and timer Within an activity
this is my AlertDialog code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialog.setTitle("...");
alertDialog.setMessage("...");
alertDialog.show();
```

and before this AlertDialog i create and run timer like this :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        timer = new Timer(false);
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(light==0) light =1;
                        else light = 0;
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = ac.getWindow().getAttributes();
                        lp.screenBrightness = light;
                        ac.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

this timer for change light of screen.
what is my problem?
is it possible to run timer with AlertDialog concurrent؟